# What does it mean to say that the wave equation admits as solutions all functions of a certain form?

Tags: waves

I have a very vague understanding of what this statement means, my understanding is that it would mean any function of a certain form can be solved when plugged into the wave equation.

What I mean is taking the second derivate of the function with respect to $z$ and the second derivate of the function with respect to $t$ and plugging those in would result in a solution.

$$ \frac{\partial^{2} y}{\partial x^{2}} = \frac{1}{v^{2}} \frac{\partial^{2} y}{\partial t^{2}} \tag{1} \label{1} $$

Is this the correct understanding of the statement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solutions to wave equation in 1+1D](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/562888/)

Answer (score 1):

For this one dimensional wave equation, what it means is that indeed you can substitute any function:

$$y=f(x \pm vt) $$

and have it be a solution to this equation. You can check it yourself, explicitly. Simply note:

$$\partial_t^2 y = v^2f'' ; \partial_x^2y=f'' $$

where $f'=\frac{df}{d(x\pm vt)}$.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a very vague understanding of what [the wave equation admits as solutions all functions of a certain form] means, my understanding is that it would mean any function of a certain form can be solved when plugged into the wave equation.

> What I mean is taking the second derivate of the function with respect to $z$
> and the second derivate of the function with respect to $t$ and plugging those in would result in a solution.
> $$\frac{\partial^{2} y}{\partial x^{2}}=\frac{1}{v^{2}} \frac{\partial^{2} y}{\partial t^{2}}\tag{1}$$
> Is this the correct understanding of the statement ?

What we mean, given your Eq. (1), is that any function that depends on $x$ and $t$ only through the combination $x+vt$ or $x-vt$ will be a solution.

For example, suppose that the argument of any twice-differentiable function of a single variable $f$ is evaluated at $x-vt$ to construct a twice-differentiable function $g$ of two variables, a la:
$$
g(x,t) \equiv f(x-vt)
$$

Then $g$ is a solution to your Eq. (1) since:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x} = f''(x-vt)
$$
and, using the chain rule of differentiation
$$
\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial t^2} = v^2\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial (-vt)^2} =v^2f''(x-vt)
$$
and thus
$$
\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}=\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial t^2}\;.
$$

The argument is pretty much the same for a different function $h$ constructed as:
$$
h(x,t) = f(x+vt)\;,
$$
where, again, $f$ is any twice-differentiable function of its argument.